# How to get a comma separated double value in a string with Regex?

Tags: c#

I want to to retrieve the Latitude and Longitude values in the following string with `Regex`. Please help me do this.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 18,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(0.6213000841833666, 73.46202224493027)
        };  
    } 
</script>
```

Here's what I have tried so far.

```
var data = await Client.GetResponse(URL);
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(data);
var script = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                .Where(x => x.Name == "script").FirstOrDefault();
if (script != null) {
    Match match = Regex.Match(script.InnerText, @"LatLng([A-Za-z0-9\-]+),$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    if (match.Success) {
        // blah blah
    } 
}
```

Comment: I think it will be hard with a regex, maybe its better to search for the `LatLng` call and parse it, like separation on the comma. Please note that this looks a bit peculiar and if the script changes, you'll have to alter your code as well.

Comment: You should provide the code you already tried, the downvote is probably due you to not providing any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    Match m = Regex.Match(xml, @"LatLng\(([\d\.]+)\,\s*([\d\.]+)\)");
    if(m.Success)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Lat:{0} - Lng:{1}", m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[2].Value));
    }
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough. I can finally take a break.

Comment: Would you mind to explain it (the pattern) a little bit further? I'm still new to these stuff.

Comment: Uff! `LatLng` is self explaining. The `\(` and `\)` stand for real brackets in text. `(` and `)` without \ build groups to be accessed by the 'Groups' of the 'Match' object. Inside the groups I look for digits or `.`. It's hard to explain it closer in a comment.

Comment: Appreciate it. Thanks a bunch for your help.

Answer (score 0):

may be this helpful for you

```
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace ConsoleApplication11
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var strings = @"<script type='text/javascript'> 
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 18,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(0.6213000841833666, 73.46202224493027)
        };  
    } 
</script>";
            var group =  Regex.Match(strings,"maps.LatLng\\((?<lat>.*?),\\s*(?<long>.*?)\\)",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups;
            var lat  = group["lat"].Value;
            var lon = group["long"].Value;
        }
    }
}
```